# Google Analytics Data Upload

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to upload my own data to analytics and create a custom report?

Basically I want to generate the data every month and upload to analytics and compare the data.

Please throw some advice and help here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about generating new pageviews, events or other interactions then no. You cannot create new hits via a data upload. You can only amend data by uploading information that is applied to existing interaction hits, and even that will (with very select exceptions in GA premium accounts) be applied only to newly incoming data, not to data that existed at the time of the upload.

You could try a self-hosted tool like [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) which is based on a MySql database that allows you to easily insert data (it is however less capable than GA in many ways). If you want to spend (lots and lots and lots of) money you can also look at Adobe Analytics which allows to create hits via a data uploads (I'm sure there are other alternatives).